# Constructor not initializing field? Shadowing?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an adjacency list and to do that I need to create an arraylist of linked lists.  When I do this cityList's size does not change to the size passed in the constructor.  I feel like this may be due to shadowing but i'm not sure how shadowing works or if that's whats happening:

```
import java.util.*;

public class AdjList{

    public ArrayList<EdgeList> cityList;

    public AdjList(int size){
        this.cityList = new ArrayList<EdgeList>(size+1);
    }   

    public void add(int vertex, int edge, int distance, float price){
        cityList.get(vertex).add(edge, distance, price);
    }
}
```

in the main class I do:

```
AdjList flights = new AdjList(numCities);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a list with `new ArrayList<EdgeList>(size+1);`, `size+1` is the initial capacity of the list, not its size. The size would remain 0 until you add elements to the list.

Adding an `EdgeList` element to the list with :

```
cityList.get(vertex).add(edge, distance, price);
```

makes no sense, since it forces you to initialize all the elements of the list from index `0` to `vertex` with an `EdgeList` instance. Otherwise `cityList.get(vertex)` throws an exception.

If you want to be able to access elements by their vertex, perhaps a `Map<Integer,EdgeList>` would be a better structure :

```
this.cityList = new HashMap<Integer,EdgeList>();
...
EdgeList el = new EdgeList();
cityList.put(vertex,el);
el.add(edge, distance, price);
```

Comment: I would even say *initial* capacity.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
```

Your code is specifying the capacity not the size. After you add elements to the list, the size will increase.